# how to git clone a project and use create-react-native-app

Tags: github, create-react-native-app

We have a school project where we forked a class project into our local repository.  Let's call that repo gitLocalHomeWork. That repo just has a few files.  We are building a react-native application.  We can use the create-react-native-app to create the native app environment.

```
create-react-native-app gitLocalHomeWork
```

how do we link or direct the react native app to the github directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some files already in the forked repo then you can use a nested folder inside that repo in which you can create react app through create-react-native-app. Below are the steps:

- Clone your forked repo to your local machine using git clone.
- Create a nested folder in your cloned repo and cd to it.
- Use create-react-native-app command to create the react app.
- Above command will create some new files, add those files to git staging are using git add command.
- Commit your changes and push to remote.